# add header Access-Control-Allow-Headers via nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

How to insert header in response request via nginx?
The fact is that a CORS error occurs during a cross-domain request, which is solved simply by adding the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header through the nginx proxy server (as I read on the Internet).
Here is cors error code:
[image]
Backend I can't change and disable cors check.

1. No headers are connected, although the application is used and works correctly. nginx config:

```js
server {
  listen 80;

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*" always;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*" always;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
  add_header Custom header value;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri//index.html;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

2. How the request works. Created a simple fetch on a backup that contains one controller. Simple get request with React:

```js
function MyPoster() {
      const [recommended, setRecommended] = useState(null);
     
      constant getPeers = () =>
        fetch('http://localhost:9002/c', {method: "GET"})
          .then(response => response.text());
     
      useEffect(() => {
        get peers()
          .then(result => {
            setRecommended(result);
          });
      }, [])
     
      return (
        <div>
          {recommended}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

3. The backup controller is also simple, which returns the results.

```js
@GetMapping("/s")
public string simpleTemplate2() {
  return "I'm a programmer";
}
```

4. Docker configuration

```js
FROM node: 12.2.0-alpine as react_build
WORKING DIRECTORY/application
COPY . /Appendix/

#prepare the container for building react
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
RUN npm run build

#preparing nginx
FROM nginx: 1.16.0-alpine

COPY --from=react_build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
copy nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

#start nginx
EXPOSURE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

https://github.com/MarkSinD/docker-nginx-react
Why are the headings not coming up? What can be added?

Comment: Did you restart nginx after updating the configuration?

Comment: Also, where is the backend? It looks like you have configured an nginx instance that only serves your frontend. Where is the backend being served from? That's where you need to manage cors.

Comment: @super
thanks!
You were right, I didn't listen to the backend. It was necessary to write another configuration on the back.
Do you think the back needs to be packed in one container with the front and nginx?

Answer (score 0):

All these headers must be set by server, that should respond to cross-origin request, i.e. http://localhost:9002, not by nginx running in container at http://localhost:3000. When your browser makes request to :9002, it knows, that it requests domain different from domain that it received running script from (i.e. :3000). So it looks for dedicated header in responce to instruct him. If this headers is not presented - request fails. It's backend responsibility to decide - are cross-origin requests permitted or not.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but the nginx should add any headings that I write. Why doesn't he add anything then?
Even add_header CustomHeader value;

Comment: Why do you think it isn't? Open browser's development tool and examine response from :3000 server in nerwork tab. And they'll be there

Comment: I didn't listen to the backend. It was necessary to write another configuration on the back.